# ClickOnce application installer when publishing WPF application shows HP Inc

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

I have made a WPF application and I use Publish to create the ClickOnce installer. When I look in the Add or Remove Programs in Control Panel then it shows 'HP Inc.'. I have searched the solution and this text is nowhere to be found. I have specified the correct information in the AssemblyInfo.cs file. Where do I specify the Publisher information and what will be displayed in the Add and Remove interface?

[image: PublisherUnknownAndHpInc.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a published wpf, you can add the publisher in the following ways:

Right-click your project in Solution Explorer=>Publish=>More actions=>Edit=>Settings=>Options=>Description=>Publisher name

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Change the Publisher name to the name you want, and click Publish after completing the editing. The effect is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a publish profile when I am publishing. I only get a Publish Wizard with a few options and no way to change the settings like on your screenshots. But your answer still helped me. I found the Publish Options in the Properties for the project. There is a Publish setting with all of the things you mention.